# Unable to collapse and showing incorrect symbols on data filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I can able to `search` or `filter` the names and can see their details from the `input search` as well as on `clicking` of given 
icons(i.e I can `expand/collapse`) in the given [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/u77ouuLn/).

But I am facing few issues like:

a).  If I `search` any name or any details from the input field, then it's `filtering` and `showing` the respective data (i.e it is `expanding` - it's fine), but I am unable to `collapse` it on `filtering`(i.e on clicking of "`-`" sign, that respective data is `not collapsing`) and after that

b). If I `remove` any searched data from the input field, then all the data is going to be `collapsed`(it's fine), but they are collapsing in "`-`" sign instead of "`+`"sign

Please help me that how to fix these things and thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

You may be over thinking it you can remove most your functions and get a working result. See the jsfiddle below for an example. If you want to have all search results expanded when searching and all results close when the search field is closed I recommend you create a filter to set all of the result to expanded or not.

```html
<div ng-controller="repeatPeople">
  <br>
  <p>
    <input type="text" id="search" ng-model="searchPeople" placeholder="Search">
  </p>
  <br>
  <br>
  <table border="0">
    <thead style="background-color: lightgray;">
      <tr>
        <td style="width: 30px;">Click</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Gender</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat-start="person in result = (people | filter:searchPeople)">
        <td>
          <button ng-if="person.expanded" ng-click="person.expanded = !person.expanded">-</button>
          <button ng-if="person.expanded == false" ng-click=" person.expanded = !person.expanded">+</button>
        </td>
        <td>{{person.name}}</td>
        <td>{{person.gender}}</td>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-if="person.expanded" ng-repeat-end="">
        <td colspan="3">{{person.details}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/rn6fcrc8/

If you want the search to expand all on search or close all on clear serach you should create a filter to handle this functionality. It should look like this :

```js
// Setup the filter
angular.module('app').filter('expandAll', function() { 

  return function(filteredPeople, people) {

      if (filteredPeople.length != people.length){
          for(var person in filteredPeople){
            person.expanded = true;
          }
      }
      else { 
          for(var person in filteredPeople){
            person.expanded = false;
          }
      }
      var output = angular.copy(filteredPeople);
      return output;

  }

});
```

Then just add the filter to your ng-repeat statement it should look like this, note that this is based off the previous jsfiddle I posted:

```
      <tr ng-repeat-start="person in result = (people | filter:searchPeople | expandAll:people)">
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, But I am not looking for it actually, it should expand on data filtering/searching default as per my Fiddle and should collpase as per my concern. I have a solution to expand/collapse like your demo, but I need like my question. Please let me know.

Comment: I have added more the answer to describe the expandAll functionality.

Comment: I mean if I run the above "Run code snippet" there, giving "Uncaught ReferenceError: app is not defined".

Comment: you need to assign the filter to the module you are using, the code snippet won't run i just put it into a code snippet for formatting. I have updated the snippet to show how to assign to a module.

Comment: I am sorry, I am getting app injection module error, I have configured as per above, but i am not sure why i am getting this. Can you please integrate this into updated fiddle please. I checked everything, it looks fine, but don't know.

Comment: 'angular.module('app').filter' is just a general example and your module is probably called something else, I am just using 'app' as i do not know the name of your module.

Comment: I have updated as per above code snippet in the  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/u77ouuLn/2/): I am getting the error: Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!  Please let me know about it and Thanks in advance !